# Cannot access props of object

Tags: reactjs

The child component was able to access the state when it is flattened -

```
this.state = {
        name: '',
        email: ''
};
```

and the following is the view code

```
    <Form
        handleFormChange={this.props.handleFormChange}
        name={this.props.name}
        email={this.props.email} />
```

But when state is structured in a nested way the component is not able to access it

```
   this.state = {
        company: {
            name: '',
            email: ''
        }
    }
```

with this corresponding view code

```
  <Form
       handleFormChange={this.props.handleFormChange}
       name={this.props.company.name}
       email={this.props.company.email} />
```

It is stating "**Cannot read property 'name' of undefined(…)**"

full component:
**company.js**

```
    export default class Company extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                company: {
                    name: '',
                    email: ''
                }
            };
        };
        render() {
            return (
                    <AddCompanyModal
                        activeAddDialog={this.state.activeAddDialog}
                        addDialog={this.addDialog}
                        saveData={this.saveData}
                        handleFormChange={this.handleFormChange} />
            )
       }
   }
```

**addCompanyModal.js**

```
export default class AddCompanyModal extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Dialog
                active={this.props.activeAddDialog}
                onEscKeyDown={this.props.addDialog}
                onOverlayClick={this.props.addDialog}
                title='Add Company Information'
                >
                <CompanyForm
                    handleFormChange={this.props.handleFormChange} />
            </Dialog>
        )
    }
}
```

**CompanyForm.js**

```
export default class CompanyForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                <Input
                    icon='business'
                    type='text'
                    label='Name'
                    name={this.state.company.name}
                    value={this.state.company.name}
                    onChange={this.props.handleFormChange.bind(this, 'name')} />
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed props and state.

```
<Form
   handleFormChange={this.props.handleFormChange}
   name={this.state.company.name}
   email={this.state.company.email} />
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: now its stating - Cannot read property 'company' of null(…) for line  name={this.state.company.name}

Comment: OK. Found it - ` this.state = {
 company: {
  name: '',
 email: ''
  }` should be in CompanyForm component - to be honest, event without the company object

Comment: so do I declare state in every child component which is using that state?

Comment: No. State should be matter of one component which holds it - in your example the form.